# Passing a quoted string to system() keeping quotes intact

Tags: perl, exec, quotes

This problem applies to Perl v5.24.0 on Windows 10

Except for the simplest cases. It is always a problem passing command lines and parameter lists between programs. Taking into account the effects of whitespace and shell metacharacters, possibly so that the data remains intact over several levels of calls, can involve a mess of escapes and quotation marks

The panacea has always been to use the multiple-parameter form of `system` (which also tries to avoid calling the shell as an intermediary) so that each parameter is reliably separated without resorting to quotes

A call like this

```
system("dir \"C:\\Program Files\\\"")
```

is much easier on the eye written like this

```
system('dir', 'C:\Program Files\\')
```

However, I can see no way to pass values that *include* enclosing quotes

If I write a test program

#### show.pl

```
use Data::Dump;
dd \@ARGV;
```

and then call

```
system('show', 'xxx')
```

then the output I get is what I expect

```
["xxx"]
```

However, suppose I want to pass the string `"xxx"`. If I try

```
system('show', '"xxx"')
```

then the quotes are stripped at some point along the way and the output is identical to the preceding example

#### How do I make a call to `system` such that the output is `["\"xxx\""]`?

I have tried all manner of escaping, but the solution evades me

Comment: Which kind of perl are you using on Windows? I just tested it on Cygwin with perl 5.22.2 and it does just what you're asking. Maybe something like activestate perl behaves differently?

Comment: Mine is Strawberry Perl v5.24.0. Please would you post your exact call to `system`?

Comment: Works for me as well on Cygwin with perl 5.14.4

Comment: Thanks @xxfelixxx. Can anyone please confirm my own results?

Answer (score 4):

The problem:

```
system($^X, '-E', 'say @ARGV', '"test"');
```

Output:

```
test
```

That's so broken!<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Solution:

```
use Win32::ShellQuote qw( quote_system );

system(quote_system($^X, '-E', 'say @ARGV', '"test"'));
```

Output:

```
"test"
```

---

1. Perl needs to build a command line even if the shell isn't used. Unlike unix where the [system call](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2freebsd.html) to execute a program takes the path to a program and a list of arguments, the Windows [system call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to execute a program takes a command line, so a command line must be built even if the shell is avoided. It appears that Perl builds the command lines incorrectly.<sup>[2]</sup> This is why using the `system BLOCK LIST` syntax doesn't help.
2. In fact, it's up to the application to parse the command line for arguments! Thankfully, there's a [system call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) to do that, so a standard has formed.